# shutil.copytree(dirs_exist) doesn't work on linux

Tags: python

I am using a Kaggle docker image (https://github.com/Kaggle/docker-python)

It complains that I'm passing this parameter. It works on Windows 10.

Is this expected functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree):

> New in version 3.8: The `dirs_exist_ok` parameter.

Care to check which version of Python the Kaggle docker image uses?